# Make PHP global variable using a MYSQL query

Tags: php, global, globalization

I am trying to use a query in WP as a Global variable ( yes I know to avoid those if possible, but This is a query I am going to reference over and over so to me it makes more sense then writing out the same query with each function). I must be missing something because the global variable doesn't seem to be working.
How I defined the variable:

```
    $query =  $wpdb->get_results("SELECT columnn1, column2 FROM mytablename");

function query() {
  global $query;
        return $query;
    };
```

Then when referencing it in a function later I used:

```
fucntion xyz{
    $results = $query;
//does things
}
```

Have I done something wrong? It isn't working.

**EDIT 1:**

```
   $query =  $wpdb->get_results("SELECT columnn1, column2

FROM mytablename");

function query() {
  global $query;
        return $query;
    };
```

Then when referencing it in a function later I used:

```
fucntion xyz{
global $query
    $results = $query;
//does things
}
```

Comment: you can use $GLOBALS['query'] to access the global value of query variable.

say you have a function where you want to use the query variable
$query = "Some string";


```function use_query_here() {
    global $query;
    $results = $query;
    //Use $results here now or you can use $query also directly but if will risk mutating its value
<br />
}```

OR

```function use_query_here() {
    $result = $GLOBALS['query'];
    // Use $result variable here now
}```

Comment: so instead it should be $results=$GLOBAL['query'] ?

Comment: Thank you so everything above it correct except that I have not defined the global $query in the function I want to use it inside of, correct?

Comment: yes, global keyword is not defining a variable in the global scope but it is to be used whenever you want to access some variable from the global scope inside of a function

Comment: I edited above with how I have it set up. It isnt working though, is my edit 1, how it should work?

Comment: Typo in your code you have written fucntion there. it should be function xyz() .....

Comment: yea sorry. That wasnt in my other code. So I can skip the function query() {
  global $query;
        return $query;
    };
And move directly to my function xyz? Or do I still need the function for global etc?

Comment: Yes you only need to use global when you want to access the global variable. So in this case you can completely remove query function as it is redundant.

Comment: thank you very much! If you put yours as an answer, I can accept it

Comment: I have added it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

try this

```php
function query() use ($query) {
    // do something with global variable $query
    return $query;
};
```

Comment: Thanks. When you say //do something with global variable $query what do I do there? Or is this instead of $results = $query?

Answer (score 0):

you can use $GLOBALS['query'] to access the global value of query variable. say you have a function where you want to use the query variable

```
$query = "Some string"; 
function use_query_here() {     
    global $query;     
    $results = $query;     //Use $results here now or you can use $query also directly but if will risk mutating its value <br /> 
}
```

OR

```
function use_query_here() {
    $result = $GLOBALS['query'];     // Use $result variable here now 
}
```